# My C Program Process terminated with status -1073741819 (0 minute(s), 8 second(s))

Tags: c

After I execute the program I get this error :

Process terminated with status -1073741819 (0 minute(s), 8 second(s))

Please also note that I get 0 warnings after compiling

Thank you very much for helping

Here is the full code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int summation(int arr[],int n);
int main()
{
    int arr[5],sum=0;
    printf("enter the elements");
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d,&arr[i]");
    }
    printf("The sum of");
    sum=summation(arr,5);
    printf("%d",sum);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
int summation(int arr[],int n)
{
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        sum=sum+arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d,&arr[i]");` -- That didn't produce a warning? The closing quote should go after the `%d`.

Comment: Please share more info, are you seeing any prints , have you tried to debug it, Where is it breaking, what input are you giving

Comment: Tip: When you get a strange looking error number like -1073741819, convert it to hexadecimal to see if it is more recognizable. -1073741819 converts to C0000005 which results in many search engine hits as the Microsoft error code for invalid memory access. While not necessarily not immediately helpful, this narrows down the search area for the bug to where you are using pointers.

Comment: @MOehm Thank You so much Sir it is working now

Comment: I'm glad it works now. If you didn't get a warning, you should probably enable them (or more of them). They can help you to catch such simple errors. (Unfortunately, many C compilers don't enable warnings by default.)

Comment: To turn on more/better compiler messages in the big three compiler families in use today you want to turn on `/W4` in Visual Studio's project properties dialogues or add the likes of `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror` to the clang or GCC command line. How this is done on your particular development environment or with a less-commonly used compiler varies too wildly to cover here. Check your tool's documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
scanf("%d,&arr[i]");
```

It should be:

```
 scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
```